# Symfony 3.4 : How to force de-authentication

Tags: symfony, security

My security user is fully authenticated with some roles got from some system. I want to check if one of the Roles exists and if it does not, I want to force de-authentication of the user.

In my event listener on the login I do this :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class SecurityEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  private $token;
  private $checker;
  private $container;
  private $session;

  public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $token, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $checker, ContainerInterface $container, SessionInterface $session) {
    $this->token = $token;
    $this->checker = $checker;
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->session = $session;
  }


  public function login() {  
    if(!$this->checker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        $this->session->invalidate();
        $this->token->setToken(null);
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    } else {
        $user = $this->token->getToken()->getUser();
        $roles = $user->getRoles();
        $found = false;

        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if($role->getRole() === $this->container->getParameter('role_expected')) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!$found) {
            $this->session->invalidate();
            $this->token->setToken(null);
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        } else {
            $user->removeAllRoles();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I tried to use the setToken to null but it does not work (Exception).

HGow should I ask to de-authenticate the user ?

Comment: The session may not have been created when the listener itself is instantiated.  You could try injecting the RequestStack then getting the session from the master request in your login method.  Not sure if it will actually help or not.  And while unrelated, you should also replace the container with just the role_expected parameter.

Comment: You seem to need to check the roles of the User being authenticated. If the user roles don't contain one you want to refuse him the authentication, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the user permissions in your controller, you could create a custom User Checker that could deny the authentication based on your custom logic.

**Sample User Checker**

```
namespace AppBundle\Security;
use AppBundle\Security\User as AppUser;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }

        if (!in_array('SOME_ROLE', $user->getRoles())) {
            // throw an AccountStatusException exception here
        }
    }
}
```

If you also want to run a check against the user roles *after* user has been logged in (if his roles could change during his session) you can use the `checkPostAuth()` method.

---

You also have to mention the use of your custom User Checker in your `app/config/security.yml` file.

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            user_checker: AppBundle\Security\UserChecker
```

More informations [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/user_checkers.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to redirect your user to your logout route.

Sadly there does not seem to be a dedicated method that will simply handle the whole logout process for you.
Except maybe if you manage to call [this method](https://github.com/symfony/security-http/blob/master/Firewall/LogoutListener.php#L73) in a valid instance of `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\LogoutListener`.

Symfony logout works like that:

- It is handled by this listener
- Listener is called on each request
- Listener checks if requested route === logout route
- If requested route === logout route, listener logs out the user

Comment: It seems that using the logout route just delete the user from the session but if I look the developement tool bar, the user is still authenticated. What I would like to do is not  to see the authenticated in the toolbar,  just to be sure.

Comment: **The user is still authenticated:** By any chance, is the user authenticated anonymously?